# Azure Active Directory B2C Phone Sign Up/Sign In Filter to Certain Countries

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've currently setup Azure Active Directory B2C for users to sign in via a phone OTP. I need to limited the phone numbers to be only countries the application is supported in.

I've not found a way to do this yet.

NB* this is not the MFA it's login via phone number.

Comment: Are you using custom policies? Does this involve the phone country code dropdown?

Comment: No I'm not using custom policies. I was trying to avoid. Yes the drop down. @rbrayb

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom policies.

You can then edit the list, e.g. [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/customising-the-phone-drop-down-in-azure-ad-b2c-774656391d2d) and [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/setting-a-default-value-for-the-phonefactor-country-drop-down-in-azure-ad-b2c-f9e7558327a3).

Comment: Thanks. I can see alot of examples where phonefactor is used and you can change the drop down on MFA. But I cannot find any example where to change the country drop down when registering with a mobile I think it's api.phoneSignUp or api.phoneInput.